# How can Titan Shifters with multiple forms control which form they transform into?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the story of *Attack on Titan*, Titan Shifters need to harm themselves to be able to transform. But when a shifter is holding 2 or more titans, how do they transform into the form of their choosing?

For example, Eren is now in control of 3 Titan powers, and he can transform into the Attack Titan by injury. How can he turn into a War Hammer Titan?

Answer (score 2):

Actually having that titan just means that the shifter has thar titan's powers. So if a shifter has multiple powers in possession, he/she will still just tranform into one body, and can use the titan power.
A little spoiler but eren will still have the titan body like he has now, and it has been regularly mentioned that he can use the war hammers power, so it doesn't mean to have a different titan body per titan power.

A Spoiler from Chapter 117 makes it clear, even if you are anime-only, it will only grow your interest, and not spoil the storyline likely -

> [image: Eren Using WarHammer]
>
>  In this, eren is using the war hammer titan's power, in his `usual` form (the one he had earlier too)

Comment: Note that the user *should be able* to use the power too, for example founding titans 'true power' can't be utilised until a direct contact or with royal blood (without the vow). Similarly say you already did 3 transformation, then the shifter should be tired enough to not be able to use war hammer titan's strength.